# How to set ICON image for java.jar executable jar file

Tags: java

I have developed a game in Java made an executable jar file `mygame.jar`.

I now want to set an ICON image to mygame.jar so that it shows my custom image instead of usual java  tea cup image.

Please don't confuse this with setting frame icon image with `frame.setImageIcon("")` method to set frame ICON image.

Comment: okay how do I get it removed from here  ??

Answer (score 0):

you should use a tool named launch4j ,you can found it here : http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/
for more informations on how to use it watch this : http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/
i hope this will be useful.